# issue with grid using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to implement a grid like layout using ng-repeat.

When the list is having empty data grid is getting alignment issues. I'm not getting where I've gone wrong.

please help me solve this. [JS Fidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolliparavamsikrishna/md31c8g5/)
HTML

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items" style=" height: 50px; width: auto;">
            <span ng-repeat="goals in item" style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid black; height: 50px; width: 100px;">
                {{goals}}
            </span>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
var n = [
["Empty","Jan","Feb","Mar","APR","MAY"],["person1",".",".",".",".","."],["person2",".",".",".",".","."],["person3",".",".",".",".","."],["person4",".",".",".",".","."],["person5","","","","",""]
]

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = n;
}
```

Comment: It seems that float:left of all span's solves the problem too.

Comment: in ie-browser you have to increase the width of all parent-divs as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a styling issue with `inline-block` elements. To fix, add `vertical-align: bottom` style.

```
<span ng-repeat="goals in item" style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid black; height: 50px; width: 100px; vertical-align: bottom">
   {{goals}}
</span>
```